# How to access index of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

```
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.className = "table";
let indexArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    for (let i = 0; i <= indexArray.length; i++) {
      if (indexArray.length === i[1]) {
        const th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerText = "Global";
        th.style.padding = "20px";
        table.appendChild(th);
      }
}
```

Hey, I'm trying to access the index of for loop to give a global text name to the first index, but I get here Global text 5 times instead of one time. Any advice

Comment: You should use ```if (i===0) {``` instead of ```if (indexArray.length === i[1]) {```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

Invalid HTML for one

Perhaps you meant this? I am guessing because you did not post expected output

```js
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.className = "table";
let indexArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  }
  var th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerText = "Global "+i;
  th.style.padding = "20px";
  tr.appendChild(th);

}
table.appendChild(tr)
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

or this

```js
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.className = "table";
let indexArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  if (i === 0) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerText = "Global";
    th.style.padding = "20px";
    tr.appendChild(th);

  } else {
    var td = document.createElement("td")
    td.textContent = indexArray[i]
    tr.appendChild(td)
  }
  table.appendChild(tr)
}

document.body.appendChild(table)
```

or this

```js
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.className = "table";
let indexArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const text = ["Global", "Local", "Special", "General", "Something else"]
var tr = document.createElement("tr");

for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerText = text[i];
  th.style.padding = "20px";
  tr.appendChild(th);
}
table.appendChild(tr)

document.body.appendChild(table)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how I change the innerText Global because I get Global Text 5 time. Like each iterate different InnerText

Comment: What do you want it to say? Your usecase is very vague

Comment: My second example gives only 1 global

Comment: With each iterate print, different InnerText.

Comment: The expected output is : global, local, special, general,
I mean, give different text name for the row.

Comment: Where do the works "local, special, general," come from. Please update the question with complete information

Comment: Thank you. I will do